# Final element in foreach() not be compared

Tags: php, arrays

I have a given array as such:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [product_colour_sizes_id] => 31822
        [product_colour_sizes_product_id] => 1495
        [product_colour_sizes_option_value_colour_id] => 377
        [product_colour_sizes_option_value_size_id] => 297
        [quantity] => 999
        [product_colour_sizes_name_sizes] => 6     
        [product_colour_sizes_name_colours] => Grey
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [product_colour_sizes_id] => 31823
        [product_colour_sizes_product_id] => 1495
        [product_colour_sizes_option_value_colour_id] => 377
        [product_colour_sizes_option_value_size_id] => 295
        [quantity] => 999
        [product_colour_sizes_name_sizes] => 7     
        [product_colour_sizes_name_colours] => Grey
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [product_colour_sizes_id] => 31824
        [product_colour_sizes_product_id] => 1495
        [product_colour_sizes_option_value_colour_id] => 377
        [product_colour_sizes_option_value_size_id] => 242
        [quantity] => 999
        [product_colour_sizes_name_sizes] => 8     
        [product_colour_sizes_name_colours] => Grey
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [product_colour_sizes_id] => 31825
        [product_colour_sizes_product_id] => 1495
        [product_colour_sizes_option_value_colour_id] => 377
        [product_colour_sizes_option_value_size_id] => 296
        [quantity] => 999
        [product_colour_sizes_name_sizes] => 9     
        [product_colour_sizes_name_colours] => Grey
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [product_colour_sizes_id] => 31826
        [product_colour_sizes_product_id] => 1495
        [product_colour_sizes_option_value_colour_id] => 377
        [product_colour_sizes_option_value_size_id] => 243
        [quantity] => 999
        [product_colour_sizes_name_sizes] => 10    
        [product_colour_sizes_name_colours] => Grey
    )

)
```

I then have a `foreach()` loop which loops over the above data and reduces down to a single array. The loop to do this is here:

```
foreach ($product_combinations as $key => $product_combination){

    // Set the offiset key.
    $offset_key = $key + 1;
    if(array_key_exists($offset_key, $product_combinations)){
        echo 'Yes' . '<br>';
    }

    // Check if the array key exists.
    if (array_key_exists($offset_key, $product_combinations)) {

        // Core logic.
        if ($product_combinations[$offset_key]['product_colour_sizes_name_colours'] == $product_combinations[$key]['product_colour_sizes_name_colours']) {

            $color = $product_combinations[$key]['product_colour_sizes_name_colours'];
            $id = $product_combinations[$key]['product_colour_sizes_option_value_size_id'];
            $sizes[$id] = $product_combinations[$key]['product_colour_sizes_name_sizes'];
            $quantity = $product_combinations[$key]['quantity'];
            $sizes['quantity'] = $quantity;

            /* Dont forget theses*/
            $sizes['product_colour_sizes_id'] = $product_combination['product_colour_sizes_id'];
            $sizes['product_colour_sizes_product_id'] = $product_combination['product_colour_sizes_product_id'];
            $sizes['product_colour_sizes_option_value_colour_id'] = $product_combination['product_colour_sizes_option_value_colour_id'];
            $sizes['product_colour_sizes_option_value_size_id' . $id_increment] =$product_combination['product_colour_sizes_option_value_size_id'];
            $id_increment++;
        }

        // Add the sizes to the color array.
        $colours[$color] = $sizes;

    } // if (==)

} // foreach
```

The problem is that this loop does not compare the last indexed array. I've tried several iterations of this logic to no avail. This is the last array which it is not looping over.

```
[4] => Array
    (
        [product_colour_sizes_id] => 31826
        [product_colour_sizes_product_id] => 1495
        [product_colour_sizes_option_value_colour_id] => 377
        [product_colour_sizes_option_value_size_id] => 243
        [quantity] => 999
        [product_colour_sizes_name_sizes] => 10    
        [product_colour_sizes_name_colours] => Grey
    )
```

The outcome from looping over the data currently gives me this result:

```
Array
(
[Grey] => Array
    (
        [297] => 6     
        [quantity] => 999
        [product_colour_sizes_id] => 31825
        [product_colour_sizes_product_id] => 1495
        [product_colour_sizes_option_value_colour_id] => 377
        [product_colour_sizes_option_value_size_id] => 297
        [295] => 7     
        [product_colour_sizes_option_value_size_id1] => 295
        [242] => 8     
        [product_colour_sizes_option_value_size_id2] => 242
        [296] => 9     
        [product_colour_sizes_option_value_size_id3] => 296
    )

)
```

However, what i want it to look like is this, with the last element compared and included:

```
[Grey] => Array
    (     
        [quantity] => 999
        [product_colour_sizes_id] => 31825
        [product_colour_sizes_product_id] => 1495
        [product_colour_sizes_option_value_colour_id] => 377
        [product_colour_sizes_option_value_size_id] => 297
        [295] => 7     
        [product_colour_sizes_option_value_size_id1] => 295
        [242] => 8     
        [product_colour_sizes_option_value_size_id2] => 242
        [296] => 9     
        [product_colour_sizes_option_value_size_id3] => 296
        [297] => 6
        [product_colour_sizes_option_value_size_id4] => 243
        [243] => 10

    )

)
```

Comment: Could it be because you're immediately incrementing $key by 1, therefore access the next row in array? `$offset_key = $key + 1;`

Comment: `if (array_key_exists($offset_key, $product_combinations))` will always fail on the last element, since it's checking whether the next index exists in the array, and it obviously doesn't when you get to the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies here:

```
  // Set the offiset key.
   $offset_key = $key + 1;
      if(array_key_exists($offset_key, $product_combinations)){
          echo 'Yes' . '<br>';
      }
```

Just as soon as yo start looping, you add +1 to your $key, effectively starting your array from position 1 instead of position 0 (your code search for n+1 position, thus 1 greater than the max array elements).

You need to change your logic here.